# How to change the background of radiobutton which is presnet in the WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have Radio button column in datagrid. I want to make the radiobutton background as green when it is checked or Red if it is unchecked. Please help me how to get this.

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="330" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,50,0,0" Name="grdDeviceInfo" VerticalAlignment="Top"
             CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="270" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Channels" Width="100" Binding="{Binding ChannelNo}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Label" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Label}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="60">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  IsEnabled="False" IsChecked="{Binding MasterStatus}" Background="#FFEB0F0F" Foreground="#FFC72B2B"></RadioButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a style to implement this, as follows:

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type RadioButton}" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property = "Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property = "Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Although, it only changes the radio button back ground. if thats what you want so GOOD!
But, if you want a whole different style to the checked\unchecked, you still need to create a style but you will need to create a whole new template, that will be changed in VisualStateManager (google)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I have one doubt. How to link this style to the radiobutton in the gridview. I am unable to change the background. This is the class i am using in codebehind. and binding the list to grid.     public class IOInformation
    {
        public string ChannelNo { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public bool MasterStatus { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Well, that is the basics of using style. you need to give this style an x:Key with the name you want, and then use on the radio button in your gridview as "Style={StaticResource RedGreenRadio}"
You can put this style in a ResourceDictionary, or in the same view xaml in "UserControl.Resources" and then you can use it only in this view.

Answer (score 0):

You can either bind the background values to a variable in your code behind and change it on the clicked event or something. Or you can name the radio button and then reference that directly in your code behind.

Personally I would use bindings but either way works.

Your Xaml would look like this

```
<RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  IsEnabled="False" IsChecked="{Binding MasterStatus}" Background="{Binding Background}" Foreground="#FFC72B2B"></RadioButton>
```

and your code behind would have a property like this

```
    private Brush background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    public Brush Background
    {
        get { return background; }
        set
        {
            background = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

I don't really know how your code base works in the background but in the test app I made I set the background in the Master Status property like so

```
    public bool MasterStatus
    {
        get { return masterStatus; }
        set
        {
            masterStatus = value;
            Background = masterStatus ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Now I think this is probably not going to do what you expect it to. This will simply just change the colour inside the check box, I suspect that you want to change the colour of the box behind. You can either do this by changing the style as ben suggested. Use this as a guide https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751600.aspx

or you can bind the Background property to the cell background color. Again I do not know the specifics of your app that will be for you to play around with.

Comment: Can u provide example. I didn't get exactly.

Comment: @sukeshkumar I have added some code to my answer. Sorry I assumed you would know what I meant when I said bind a property because your code contained some bound properties. Does the code help you?